# Counting character frequencies in a Swift string

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert Java code to Swift and facing the issue:

> single-quoted string literal found, use `'"' charArray[(s[i].asciiValue)! - ('a'.asciiValue)!]++ ^~~ "a"`

---

Java Code:

```
for(String s: str){
    char arr[] = new char[26]

    for(int i =0;i< s.length(); i++){
        arr[s.charAt(i) -'a']++;
    }
}
```

Swift Code:

```
extension String {
    var asciiArray: [UInt32] {
        return unicodeScalars.filter{$0.isASCII}.map{$0.value}
    }
}

extension Character {
    var asciiValue: UInt32? {
        return String(self).unicodeScalars.filter{$0.isASCII}.first?.value
    }
}

class GroupXXX {

    func groupXXX(strList: [String]) {
        for str in strList {
            var charArray = [Character?](repeating: nil, count: 26)
            var s = str.characters.map { $0 }

            for i in 0..<s.count {
                charArray[(s[i].asciiValue)! - ('a'.asciiValue)!]++
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There are more problems: There is no `++` in Swift, `s[i]` won't compile because strings cannot be indexed with integers,  incrementing an optional Character makes no sense, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your Swift code:

- There are no single-quoted character literals in Swift (as already [explained 
  by JeremyP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098414/1187415)).
- The `++` operator has been removed in Swift 3.
- `s[i]` does not compile because Swift strings are not indexed by
  integers.
- Defining the array as `[Character?]` makes no sense, and you cannot
  increment a `Character?`. The Swift equivalent of the Java `char`
  would be `UInt16`.
- You don't check if the character is in the range "a"..."z".

Apparently you want to count the number of occurrences of
each character "a" to "z" in a string.
This is how I would do it in Swift:

- Define the "frequency" array as an array of integers.
- Enumerate the `unicodeScalars` property of the string.
- Use a switch statement to check for the valid range of characters.

Then the custom extension are not needed anymore and the code becomes

```
var frequencies = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 26)
for c in str.unicodeScalars {
    switch c {
    case "a"..."z":
        frequencies[Int(c.value - UnicodeScalar("a").value)] += 1
    default:
        break // ignore all other characters
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
charArray[(s[i].asciiValue)! - ('a'.asciiValue)!]++
```

As the error says, use double quotes, Swift doesn't have a syntax that differentiates between characters and strings (characters themselves may be sequences of bytes in swift).

You may need to explicitly force the character to be a `Character` if the compiler can't differentiate.

```
charArray[(s[i].asciiValue)! - (Character("a").asciiValue)!]++
```

Comment: after making above change seeing below error  cannot pass immutable value to mutating operator: 'charArray' is immutable
               charArray[(s[i].asciiValue)! - (Character("a").asciiValue)!]++